# Why does indexing a record type yield a non-undefined type?

Tags: typescript

To my surprise, the call of `.toLowerCase` here is not a type error.

```
const stuff: Record<string, string> = {a: 'A', b: 'B'}
stuff.z.toLowerCase()
```

[See in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCuAzRAuGAlApqATgEwB5ocBLMAcwBo4pSKA+GAXhgG8BDNAcgEEvqARtwBCXAL4AoBMgB0ALxlQQAGRAB3TDgDC7CJgAUASglA)

The inferred type of indexing the record with *any* string, is the value type of the record.

In my real situation, `stuff` contains run-time variable data. In general, surely the type of `stuff[k]` should be `string|undefined`? Why isn't it?

Comment: Fortunately we've foreseen this and have added the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag: https://tsplay.dev/m0narw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74491685/typescript-assumes-that-literally-any-key-is-guaranteed-to-exist-on-a-record Another recent question about the same behaviour, with an answer